# Missing code to login this website and scrape needed data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am trying to scrape data from my goods provider website in order to easier populate and update some fields of my product info. I achieved to get all the data except 6 pieces of text which are only available when I logged in.

What I should add to my code so that it keeps my logged in request after request and I am able to get all the needed data?

The login page of the provider website is this one: (some advanced programmer could take a look at the login method the website uses through browser dev tools?)

[Login webpage](https://online.feliubadalo.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9vbmxpbmUuZmVsaXViYWRhbG8uY29tL2N1c3RvbWVyL2FjY291bnQvbG9nb3V0U3VjY2Vzcy8%7E/)

This is my test code to try to get logged in:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tryingToGetLoggedIn()
 
    Const Url$ = "https://online.feliubadalo.com/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9vbmxpbmUuZmVsaXViYWRhbG8uY29tL2N1c3RvbWVyL2FjY291bnQvbG9nb3V0U3VjY2Vzcy8~/"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Dim Container As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    
    Dim authCreds As String
    authCreds = "xxx@xxx.xxx:xxxx"
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"        
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", authCreds
        .send

    
    End With


End Sub
```

And this is my test code to try to get data from logged session (without success):

```
Option Explicit

Sub tryingToGetDataBehindLogin()
 
    Const Url$ = "https://online.feliubadalo.com/cerveza-de-trigo-bio-vegan-singluten-330ml-ekotrebol"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Dim Container As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
 
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"        
        .send

        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
         
        
        Dim obj_title1 As Object
        Set obj_title1 = Html.getElementsByClassName("attribute-title")
     
        Dim title1 As String
        title1 = test1.Item(0).innerText
        
        Debug.Print title1
    
    End With


End Sub
```

After trying login with the exposed code, the response info from xhr object (XMLHTTPRequest) (oHttp.responseText) is this one:

expirableSectionNames": ["cart","persistent"],
"cookieLifeTime": "31536000",
"updateSessionUrl": "https\u000312CAB\u00023FF9\u001362Fonline.feliubadalo.com\ u001362Fcustomer\ u001362Faccount\u001362FupdateSession\u001362"

All this info means that I am logged in? If so, what should I add to my code so that I can maintain session and get data in the next requests?

Thank you for your help